# aiogram bot stands during function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiogram

I wrote a bot to get photo charts in tradingview:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
import sellbot
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from datetime import datetime


bot = Bot(token='54443480yi5vzrjMRivQ')
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    req = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['get'])
async def get(message):
    await Form.req.set()
    await message.answer(f'\U0001F916 request format:\nrialto\nticker\ntimeframe (minutes)')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.req)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.finish()
    splitmsg = message.text.split('\n')
    rialto, symbol, timeframe = splitmsg
    ticker = f'{rialto}:{symbol}'
    url = sellbot.send_chart(ticker, timeframe) #the function
    await message.answer_photo(url)


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

which calls another function to get the url, it takes about 12 seconds to get it, and the bot stops and does not respond to other users, how can this be fixed?
here the func:

```
def screenshot(driver, ticker, timeframe):
    chart_url = config.urls["tvchart"] + ('?symbol=' + ticker) if ticker != 'NONE' else ''
    driver.get(chart_url)
    time.sleep(1)
    ActionChains(driver, duration=1).send_keys(timeframe).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).key_down('s').key_up(
        Keys.ALT).perform()
    time.sleep(2.5)
    clipboard = Tk().clipboard_get()
    return clipboard

def send_chart(ticker, timeframe):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    driver = setup()
    driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com")
    driver.add_cookie('...')
    screenshot_preurl = screenshot(driver, ticker, timeframe)
    return screenshot_url
```

here are the functions i use

Answer (score 1):

You can launch `screenshot` and `send_chart` functions in a new thread so they work in parallel to the thread where your bot is running so that your bot doesn`t stop. But there is a problem: you can not get back from these new threads to the old thread where your bot is running. One of the possible solutions is to send photo to users of the chart through requests to Telegram API from these new threads.

So, here is the code for running your functions in a new thread:

```
#make sure to import threading
from threading import Thread

#put this code into your bot`s async function where you need to run 
#screenshot and send_chart functions

th1 = Thread(target=screenshot, args=(<your_args_here>))
th1.start()

th2 = Thread(target=send_chart, args=(<your_args_here>))
th2.start()
```

Make sure to pass ID of the user to whom photo of the chart will be sent into send_chart function.
In the end of send_chart function include following code, to send photo to the user with user_id you have passed into the function through telegram API (replace values with you actual values):

```
base_url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{<your_bot_token>}/"

user_id = "<USER_ID_TO_SEND_TO>"
photo_path = "<PATH_TO_YOUR_PHOTO>"

payload = {
    "chat_id": user_id,
}

files = {
    "photo": photo_data,
}

upload_url = f"{base_url}sendPhoto"
response = requests.post(upload_url, data=payload, files=files)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Photo sent successfully!")
else:
    print("Failed to send the photo. Response:", response.text)
```